# Ubuntu - How to replace language shortcut from only Super key

Tags: ubuntu, input, keyboard, shortcut, super

While installing Ubuntu 20 (upgraded from 18) the wizard let me choose the key combination for changing input language. The key combination I had in Ubuntu 18 was Super+space, but I didn't find it there and chose "Super" (alone).

I don't know how to change it - in "Settings" it says that the current combination is "Super+space" (which is not the only one).

Now I cannot do anything with any combination with "Super" - it only changes the input language.

See image: [I can change the other two, but not the "Left Win"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrghS.png)

Answer (score 2):

it worked, thx, but now indicator En is freezed in one position... Its always was a linux problem - creating non-existing problem and spending hours to solve them)))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Indicator freezed because of the Wayland. Just log out, and choose X11 instead on login screen

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!!

Apparently, in "Tweaks" app (previously named TweaksUI), on the "Keyboard & Mouse" menu there is a button named "Additional Layout Options".
When I clicked on it a pop-up opened and I opened the "Switching to another layout" sub-menu and found the problematic checkbox (Left Win) and un-checked it. So simple (when you know how).

In order to install "Tweaks" just run this on terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

As for Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS gnome-tweak-tool is dropped.
The following workaround can resolve the issue - https://askubuntu.com/a/1442607